# Decreasing run time of "OpenByUrl" command

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to build a web app that uses data from a certain google spreadsheet. The page loading takes a lot of time and I managed to find that the command that takes the most time is this one:

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/path").getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
```

I want to decrease the run time of the command.
Is there a way to make the script run faster? or maybe to make some functions run parallelly?

Also, is there a way to prioritize this script \ sheet connection over other scripts or connections belonging to the same project?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the webapp with this spreadsheet, you can use

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
```

To bind copy your webapp code, open the spreadsheet needed, then click Extensions menu > Apps script  and paste it there.